# Can I get somehow the data of an input tag (text) from HTML to my Flask app as a variable without a form?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

Or are there any solutions to pass multiple variables with an `a` html tag with a `url_for` href?

My problem is that I can't get the data of the input tag with form since I use a dynamic URL that looks like:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('polling', Qid=question.name, option=1) }}"> Vote </a>
```

I want to use the data of the input tag in my route:

```py
@app.route('/polling/<Qid>/<option>')
def polling(Qid, option):
    return redirect(url_for('results', Qid=Qid))
```

Comment: If you are using an element like this, and wish to post or get data from a different route, you need to use ajax. A reload or an ajax call is the only way to gather data from a different route

Answer (score 0):

To answer part of your question:

> Or are there any solutions to pass multiple variables with an a html tag with a url_for href?

Yes, you can pass multiple variables to `url_for` without any problem:

`main.py`

```py
from flask import Flask, url_for, redirect, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route("/polling/<Qid>/<option>")
def polling(Qid, option):
    return redirect(url_for('results', Qid=Qid))

@app.route("/results/<Qid>")
def results(Qid):
    return "Redirected Correctly to Question: " + Qid 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`home.html`

```html
<!doctype html>

{% set questionname = 'Q1' %}

<a href="{{ url_for('polling', Qid=questionname, option=1)}}">Vote</a>
```